# Using sys.stdout.write() to create multiple files in NiFi?

Tags: json, python-3.x, apache-nifi

I have a pipeline in NiFi that pulls down some invalid JSON that I need to clean up. The best solution I've concocted is to run a Python script via `ExecuteStreamCommand` and simultaneously clean/split it up in one fell swoop. However, even though I use `sys.stdout.write()` in my for loop, only the original JSON comes out in the output stream in NiFi.

Am I misusing `sys.stdout.write()` or is this possible, but I've just done something wrong? My end goal is for each line of the json to be a new flow file, i.e. file 1 is `{"fruit":"apple",...`, file 2 is `{"fruit":"cherry",...`, and so on.

example JSON

```
{"fruit":"apple", "vegetable":"celery", "location":{"country":"nor\\way", "city":"oslo", }, "color":"blue"}
{"fruit":"cherry", "vegetable":"kale", "location":{"country":"france", "city":"calais", }, "color":"green"}
{"fruit":"peach", "vegetable":"peas", "location":{"country":"united\\kingdom", "city":"london", }, "color":"yellow"}
```

script

```
import json
import re
import sys

flow_file = sys.stdin.read()
try:
    load = json.loads(flow_file)
    sys.stdout.write(flow_file)
except:
    flow_file_esc = re.sub(r"[(\\)]", "", flow_file)
    for f in flow_file_esc.splitlines():
        sys.stdout.write(str(f))
```

Comment: `ExecuteStreamCommand` produces only one out-file for one in-file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clean the file first with ReplaceText and then split it with SplitJson, SplitRecord, or ForkRecord?

If you need to combine the two operations and want to script it, you could try ExecuteScript with Jython (since it doesn't look like you're using native CPython libraries), I have some simple examples in [my cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922) and [my blog](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/03/executescript-json-to-json-revisited_14.html).

Comment: When I run it through ReplaceText it goes to the failure route, but produces no error message? And I checked the file to see if the error came out as an attribute but I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: Maybe try the regex in an online tester to make sure it's matching correctly?